# mySQL rank order by sum of values in table that have it name in in another table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have two mySQL database table, I'm using one to store to product information and the other to store the sales information of product sold, where it receive my product_id as the product it sold

product Table example

```
 product_id |  prod_name |
 ------------------------
 1          |  toyota    | 
 2          |  lexus     |   
 3          |   wagon    |
```

sale Table example

```
 sale_id |  prod_id  | qty
 ------------------------
 1       |  1        |  5
 2       |  1        |  1 
 3       |  3        |  2
 4       |  1        |  4
 5       |  2        |  5
 6       |  2        |  1
```

Now i want the mysqli datebase to tabulate the sum of the most sold product name using php and html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this query

```
SELECT 
product.product_id,
product.prod_name,
sum(qty) as total 
FROM sale 
INNER JOIN product 
ON 
sale.prod_id=product.product_id 
GROUP BY 
product.product_id 
ORDER BY
total DESC
```

this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17fdb37/1/0) if you want to see the results

and you just need to echo the column name if you want to show it to your table on php

Comment: yeah it worked, thank so much but how will i be able to construct it in PHP and html it will print it.